# Problemas con Enums

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente `enum`

```
public enum Tipo
{
    Tipo0 = 0,
    Tipo1 = 1,
    Tipo2 = 2,
    Tipo3 = 3
}
```

El cual lo utilizo en mi modelo de la siguiente forma

```
public class MiModeloViewModel
{
    public Enums.Tipo Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Desde la vista todo esto se convierte en un `input type hidden` (¿como puedo convertir esta linea en razor?)

```
<input type="hidden" id="Tipo" name="Tipo" value="@Tipo.Tipo1" />
```

El primer problema que tengo es que en el `value` me queda el texto de mi `enum` en este caso quedaria `value="Tipo1"` lo que necesito es que quede el valor en entero, para ello lo solucione agregando un `value="@Tipo.Tipo1.GetHashCode()"` haciendo que ahora aparesca asi `value="1"`.

Pero al momento de enviar mi formulario, en mi modelo me trae nuevamente el valor en string de ese `enum`. ¿Que puedo hacer para que me devuelva el entero?

Hacer algo como

```
public class MiModeloViewModel
{
    public Enums.Tipo.GetHashCode() Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Claramente esto no funciona... pero esa es la idea que en vez contener el string de mi `enum` que me contenga el `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias poder utilizar Enum.parse, 
seria algo asi:

```
var EnumValue =  Enum.Parse(typeof(Tipo), TuEnumString);
```

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo desde mi controller pero no me funciona...

Comment: el enum tipo es publico y accesible desde el controlador ?

Comment: Si, donde me pierdo es con este `TuEnumString` ¿que seria?

Comment: ese es el valor que estas recibiendo, el problema es que recibes un dato tipo string en lugar del dato tipo enum, con eso transformas el string en un enum

Comment: Es que yo no recibo un `string`, recibo un `Enum` pero en vez de recibir el campo entero de mi `Enum` estoy recibiendo el campo `string`

Comment: Por que lo estaba usando de esta manera... `model.Tipo = Enum.Parse(typeof(Tipo), model.Tipo);` pero me manda un error por que me pide un string como ultimo param